# ReactDOMServer.renderToString is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-server

I render react component on server and when go to route get error message:

[image]

```
  const renderToString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString
  const fac = React.createFactory(React.createClass({
    render: function() { 
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={location} context={routeContext}>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      )
  }}))

  const appHtml = renderToString(fac())
```

Comment: Do you import/require `renderToString` somehow?

Comment: Yes, renderToString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString

Comment: Do you have something like `import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'.` at the top lines of your .js file?

Comment: If I console.log ReactDOMServer.renderToString it return function

Comment: Ok, and what if you try to call `renderToString` like this `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`?

Comment: Have the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you write it like this:

```
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={location} context={routeContext}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you!! I was looking for this exact functionality.